# Use hydrate() with async. components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-fiber

The application I'm working on is based on React Fiber and React Router V3.

Trying to use `hydrate()` instead of `render()` with [async components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback) I've faced with the following issue: HTML returned from SSR is different from client-side one.

As a result React remounts the whole DOM and throws the following warning: `Did not expect server HTML to contain...`.

React Training does not provide solution as well: [Code-splitting + server rendering](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting/code-splitting-server-rendering)

Is there any solution to achieve this?

### Updates:

#### Simple Example

*(pseudo code)*

**App.js:**

```
export default () => <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>;
```

**client.js:**

```
const createRoutes = store => ({
  path: '/',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require('./App'); // some async require
  },
  onEnter: (nextState, replace, cb) => {
    store.dispatch(fetchData())
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch(cb);
  }
});

match({history, routes: createRoutes(store)},
  (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  hydrate(
    <Router history={history} routes={createRoutes(store)} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});
```

**server.js**

```
match({routes: createRoutes(store), location: req.url},
  (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  const content = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
  // send content to client
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been investigated the issue a bit more deeper and found the solution.
To achieve DOM hydration the following point should be token in account:

1. I the example above in `client.js` I invoked `createRoutes(store)` twice. This is redundant because `renderProps` already has `routes` property prepared for `<Route />` component. Due to this mistake `onEnter` was called twice, so data fetching was performed twice too.
2. To avoid HTML mismatch on server and client side data fetching in `onEnter` should not be called on the first client-side render.
3. `match` function waits for `getComponent` callback is performed before render. So the main question is wrong, because this functionality is available out of the box.